# Java assignment from parameter or instance variable

Tags: java, variables, parameters, instance, variable-assignment

In terms of programming style, which of the following two options is better?

Option 1

```
public class A {
    private int x, y;

    public A (int z) {
    this.x = z
    this.y = this.x
    }
}
```

Option 2

```
public class A {
    private int x, y;

    public A (int z) {
    this.x = z
    this.y = z
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

***Both are same***...
But i think if you look at code option 2 looks better because you dont even have to rad it to understand
why make things complected, if there is no benefit...

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, I don't think there is any difference. If you really must choose one, I'd go with the second one as it is easier to read and understand.